# When one css class is active change preceding body class atttributes

Tags: css

i'm trying to use css to control my pages' parent body class when the class '.overlay-scale.open' is active on the page. 'overlay-scale.open' is active when an overlay is open on the page. When that overlay is active I want to stop the body from scrolling.

I gave it a go myself but it doesnt seem to be working. Trying to figure out if this is possible or another way to do it!?

My html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body class="blog">

<div id="wrapper" class="container">
<section class="full_width row">
<div class="d1-d5 sidebar">
<ul>
<li class="group"><a class="global_btn" id="trigger-s-overlay">All articles</a></li>
</ul>


</div>
<div class="d6-d12 content_body">
<h2>Hi Ray, for those who are unaware would you care to introduce yourself?</h2>

<p>Content</p>

</div>
</section>

<div class="s-overlay overlay-scale search_overlay">
<article class="d4-d6 t3-t4 m3-m4 entry">
stuff
</article>
</div>
</section>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.overlay-scale.open body.blog{
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
```